# Add date and Time to Android calendar

Tags: android, calendar

I am converting this String **Mon, 11 Feb 2013 08:00:00 CST** to date using the following code

```
Date date = null;
long starttime,endtime;
try {
    date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:Ss z").parse(tit1);
                
} catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and adding this date to calendar using the below code

```
try{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();   
    starttime=date.getTime();
    endtime=date.getTime();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    intent.putExtra("beginTime",starttime);
    intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
    intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
    intent.putExtra("endTime", endtime);
    intent.putExtra("title",tit);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

the event is adding like Mon, 11 Feb 2013.
I need to add the event look like the following

```
From: Mon, 11 Feb 2013 08:00AM
To:   Mon, 11 Feb 2013 08:30AM
```

how can I do it with the following String and Simple Date Format style.

**P.S.** :: starttime & endtime are long datatype

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem in getting date format.please check it and do as like following

if your are getting the data as follows `Date = May 05, 2012, 07:10PM`, then convert the date to be in number format a May to be 05 and pass the value in the following code.

```
Calendar beginCal = Calendar.getInstance();
beginCal.set(year, mnth, day, hrs, min);
startTime = beginCal.getTimeInMillis();

Calendar endCal = Calendar.getInstance();
endCal.set(year, mnth, day, hrs, min);
endTime = endCal.getTimeInMillis();     

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, summary);
intent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, summary);
intent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "");     
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, beginCal.getTimeInMillis());
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endCal.getTimeInMillis());
intent.putExtra(Events.ALL_DAY, allDayFlag);
intent.putExtra(Events.STATUS, 1);
intent.putExtra(Events.VISIBLE, 0);
intent.putExtra(Events.HAS_ALARM, 1);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i am getting the date in the following manner from rss feed  "Mon, 11 Feb 2013 08:00:00 CST" is there any way to convert this into required format